# How can i join same tablet in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I have 3 tables:

Table1:

```
Myid     description
P         Pera
M         Mela
```

Table2:

```
Myid     description
B         Banana
C         Ciliegia
```

Table3:

```
Myid     description
N        Noce
Z        Zenzero
```

I need this result order by Myid

```
Table    MyId  Description
Table2   B     Banana
Table2   C     Ciliegia
Table1   M     Mela
Table3   N     Noce
Table1   P     Pera
Table3   Z     Zenzero
```

Is it possible?

Br,Alessandro

Comment: Why you have 3 tables with same structure?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select 'Table1' as `table`, Table1.* from Table1
union all select 'Table2', Table2.* from Table2
union all select 'Table3', Table3.* from Table3
order by description
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a valid query.

Comment: @UncleCarl What part?

Comment: "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* from Table1
union all select 'Table2', * from Table2
union all select 'Table3'' at line 1"

Comment: @UncleCarl Thank you for the report. The query is fixed now.